# Problema con mi login PHP No Inicia

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo un problema que no le consigo solución tengo mi proyecto en el cuál estoy trabajando desde hace una semana y en mi localhost funciona de maravilla el  login luego cuando lo subo a un hosting gratuito[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELpHn.jpg) para ir afinando detalle no inicia aún colocando usuario y contraseña correcta sigue en el index [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Programando desde un smartphone, una semana poco me parece para depurar un error... :)

Answer (score 0):

Un gusto saludarte espero te encuentres bien. Viendo tu código puedo observar los errores, lo coloqué en mi entorno local y lo probé, pero no sé en sí exactamente el error que te da.

Pude ver varios problemas que tienes, definido en que te falta la variable $mysqli arriba de la variable $query. Así:

```
// Te falta esto.
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "DB_USERNAME", "DB_PASSWORD", "DB_NAME");
```

También en el or die, te hace falta especificarle un parámetro a la función
debería quedar así:

```
mysqli_error($mysqli)
```

De resto todo debería funcionar, el HTML no se le realizó ninguna actualización, a mi ya me funcionó con eso, te adjunto mi código y la respuesta que me da.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // Te falta esto.
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "first_login");
    //


    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE `username` = '$username' and `password` = '$password'") or die ("Problemas al insertar".mysqli_error($mysqli));
    
    $fetch = $query->fetch_array();

    $row = $query->num_rows;
    if($row > 0){
        // Acá le colocas la sesión.
        echo "<center><label style='color:green;'>Login realizado correctamente</label></center>";
    }else{
        echo "<center><label style='color:red;'>Contraseña o usuario inválido consulte a su proveedor de servicio</label></center>";
    }
}
```

Así me responde cuando encuentra:

[image: login success]

Y así cuando no encuentra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda amigo si funciona y está más ordenado pero no me redirige a Home.php

Comment: El artículo que redirecciona al home.php es el header("location: home.php")

Comment: if($row > 0){
            session_start();
   $_SESSION['admin_id'] = $fetch['admin_id'];
   header('location:home.php');
        Revise el código de acuerdo a tus sugerencias recibe la el echo de login realizado pero no me redirecciona a home.php